# About the reference title in the Videx form (Germany visa)

Tags: schengen-visas

I will apply for a German tourist visa and I will stay in 3 different hotels. When I fill in the reference title, I select the hotel option but there is only one hotel option.

How do I enter the address of the other 2 hotels? Or, how should it be filled in correctly?